# Ionic 4 navigate to another page inside modal

Tags: ionic4

I have a modal and everytime when I have to navigate to other pages I have to close the modal and then go to that page. But I want to navigate to a particular page without dismissing the modal. Means opening page inside modal without really dismissing it and passing back data from that page to modal.

Is it possible to do it?

Thank you in advance

My code  :

.ts to create modal

```
 async address_modal(){
   // console.log("clicked")
   console.log(this.user_id)
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: AddressModalPage,
      cssClass : 'address-modal',
      componentProps : {
        user_id : this.user_id
      } 
    });
    return await modal.present();
  }
```

html to open modal from button

```
  <ion-button(click)="address_modal()"> </ion-button>
```

modal.html // open another page

```
<ion-button routerLink="menu/items/address/add-address" style="text-transform:none" color= "primary" fill ="clear"  (click) = "add_address()" >
    <ion-icon name="add" ></ion-icon> Add new address
</ion-button>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem here is the routerLink, but i'm not really sure about this.
When i want to navigate from a modal to another page i use this.

```
export class test implements OnInit{ 

 constructor(private router: Router) { }

  moveNext(){
   this.router.navigate([page]);
  }

}
```

You just need to import this: import { Router } from '@angular/router';. And then put it on a button like this:

```
<ion-button expand="block" (click)="moveNext()">Go to next page </ion-button>
```

Comment: Did not work for me. Plus some of my components that I use within the modal do have routerLinks on them. :|